# Best way for implement multiprocess logging (C++)

Tags: c++, logging, multiprocessing

I search of mechanism for implement multiprocess logging (cross-platform solution, windows and linux). Currently, i see only one way - use log file with locking. Lock - write, unlock.

But may be somebody know something better?

Comment: Is it a hard requirement to have logging output from multiple processes in the same file?

Comment: Is it possible to log onto a DB ?

Comment: Start by looking for a framework that supports this. Something like logging you should use off the shelve components.

Comment: It's a hard requirement to log in one file from different operating system. So you will need a log server in the network. Lock/Unlock is not sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a logger application and send log entries to it over TCP sockets.

Answer (score 2):

The good partner is Producer/Consumer.

Each thread enqueues in a list. And one thread consume this list and write in a file.

Comment: I think about it. I just see one potential problem - memory. That should be shared and we have a limit. If one of applications produce many log entries log application doesn't have enough memory for consume it and some of log entries are missed or overwrited.

Comment: @Torsten yes but you will have this problem anyway. If you enqueue in a socket, that's the same problem. But you can have some kind of adaptive sampling strategy that can handle the problem. Like if you are getting close the bounding limit of the queue you start en-queuing only x% of the logs.